# Insert into database multiple rows from xml, no error

Tags: mysql, xml, insert

I have a situation, i don't know why the code below inserts only one row in the database although i get 4000+ rows from the xml file. It seems there is something wrong with the insert query that I don't understand. Any help is appreciated.

```
foreach($produse as $key => $val) {
        echo $val['cod'] . ' - ' . $val['producator'] . '<br/>';  

        mysqli_query($con, "
                        INSERT INTO 
                            aa_produse_royal 
                        (
                            activ, 
                            stoc,
                            cod,
                            denumire,
                            grupa,
                            producator,
                            descriere,
                            valuta,
                            pret,
                            pret_lei,
                            data_adaugare,
                            link_producator,
                            poze,
                            poze_noi
                        ) 
                        VALUES 
                        (
                            1,
                            '" . $val['stoc'] . "',
                            '" . $val['cod'] . "',
                            '" . $val['denumire'] . "',
                            '" . $val['grupa'] . "',
                            '" . $val['producator'] . "',
                            '" . $val['descriere'] . "',
                            '" . $val['valuta'] . "',
                            '" . $val['pret_lista'] . "',
                            '" . $val['pret'] . "',
                            CURDATE(),
                            '" . $val['link'] . "',
                            '" . $val['imagini'] . "',
                            1
                        ) 
                        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                        activ=VALUES(activ),
                        stoc=VALUES(stoc),
                        valuta=VALUES(valuta),
                        pret=VALUES(pret),
                        pret_lei=VALUES(pret_lei),
                        data_modificare=CURDATE()
                    ") or die(mysqli_error($con));
        //echo $val['cod']."<br>";
    }
echo "S-au introdus in baza de date  " . mysqli_affected_rows($con) . " randuri";
```

Comment: Use mysql_error() to get further info: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp

Comment: What error do you get? Does your file execute successfully? Is it the last row from the xml that gets inserted or the first row? Your question has very little detail.

Comment: is the first row, and  i get no error, that's weird

Comment: the mysqli_affected_rows($con) i get 2 rows afected in response but in the DB is only one row, I have a little bit up in the code this /* IF THE PRODUCTS FROM FEED ARE LOADED CONTINUE TO NEXT STEP */
if(isset($produse)) { 
 if(count($produse)>50) {  and i get 4356 products loaded